# Strange margin change in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, margins

For some reason, my bibliography margin has changed after a certain entry.  I've attached an image of what's happening.

[image]

When I shuffled sources around, I found that it always happens at that particular bibliography entry.  So, I checked the .bbl file and found this in the preceding entry:

`\newblock 10.1007/978-3-540-92219-3_20.`

Removing that fixes the problem.  The thing is, I'd like for DOI and URL entries to be included in my bibliography.  Should I be doing something differently?

Comment: I can't see any picture being attached, maybe due to your rep. However, this might be a result of a bad entry in the bib-file. The number looks like a doi and might not be enclosed in correct {}. Search your bib file for this number and check the entry

Comment: Hmm...that would be because I can't post images with less than 10 reputation.  Either way, that did fix the problem...would you post that as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: Image posted [here](http://img163.imageshack.us/i/bibproblem.png/)...thanks!

Comment: I've embedded the image. @Martin: please post the answer, your answer should be accepted because it resolved this special case, not mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment of the question, the error is in the bib file. The number is a doi and apparently there is a closing } missing. I figure that you are using biblatex and doi's are normally automatically typeset as verbatim/url.

Find this number in the bib file and check that the doi is enclosed in {}

Answer (score 3):

The underscore `_` in `10.1007/978-3-540-92219-3_20` may cause a problem because `_` is the command for subscripts and requires math mode.

- You could use `\_`
- Or use `\textunderscore` (perhaps encoding dependent, I recommend to use T1: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
- You could use the [`underscore`](http://ctan.org/pkg/underscore) package
- you could use commands of the [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) package such as `\path` or `\url`. `\urlstyle{same}` would use the normal text font.
- If the bibliography style supports underscores or URLs, use braces, already recommended by Martin-H in his comment.

Comment: Stefan, see Martin H's comment above. It is a `doi` entry with missing `{ }`, which causes the verbatim printing of this entry to fail. AFAIK it uses `\url` already internally.

Comment: @Martin: I've seen it. I guess I let my answer here for now because it's dealing with the cause and the general solution. I asked Martin do make an answer out of his comment as well to be accepted. Thanks for taking care (and your many great tipps here).